# PHP doesn't download full file

Tags: php, large-files

I am using the following script to download big files (from 600mb to around 2gb) but the PHP stops after downloading 30-40mb. I am running this on my hosting with 1gbps network connectivity so no issue with that.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file_source = $_POST['url'];
    $file_target = $_POST['name'];
    set_time_limit(0);
    $rh = fopen($file_source, 'rb');
    $wh = fopen($file_target, 'w+b');
    if (!$rh || !$wh) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!feof($rh)) {
        if (fwrite($wh, fread($rh, 4096)) === FALSE) {
            return false;
        }
        echo ' ';
        flush();
    }

    fclose($rh);
    fclose($wh);

    return true;
}
?>


<form method="post">
    NAME : <input type="text" name="name" required><br><br>
    URL : <input type="text" name="url" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>**strong text**
```

Comment: May be your max_execution_time in php.ini is limiting the script execution. you should check that and increase it to suitable value if it is less than you require and try again.

Comment: @SajeshBahing  Let me try

Comment: Are there any errors that pop up from anywhere? Try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and see if anything pops up. Also webserver logs may have some more info

Comment: @apokryfos No erros just script , page loads as normal after executing

Comment: Does it execute `return false` (which doesn't do anything in the code you shared) or does it just  think that the end of file was reached?

Comment: Try to increase execution time of script: set_time_limit(1800) /* 30 minutes */

Comment: @SajeshBahing  Dint worked

Comment: @TaronSaribekyan Dint worked

Comment: You restarted the server? @Alive ColdJuan

Comment: @SajeshBahing  Can you contact me on kik messenger ? ill tell you url which would get more easier , as it is url of my admin page

Comment: @SajeshBahing i did not

Comment: @Alive ColdJuan Please try after restarting the server and try, then if it does not work, i will contact you on kik messenger.

Comment: @SajeshBahing  ohk , also this was first testing of the script , im try to restart server

Comment: @SajeshBahing Dint worked

Comment: @SajeshBahing My kik username alivecj

Comment: Join here please [link](Can you join here? http://irc.lc/irchighway/stackoverflow/irctc@@@) i will message you here

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` file:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2G

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 2G
```

[More about php ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)

Files bigger then 2gb are not possible due to apache's limit of POST sizes(2gb)
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file_source = $_POST['url'];
    $file_target = $_POST['name'];
    set_time_limit(0);

    file_put_contents( $file_target, fopen( $file_source, 'r' ) );

}
?>


<form method="post">
    NAME : <input type="text" name="name" required><br><br>
    URL : <input type="text" name="url" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>**strong text**
```